# Hybris product configuration

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

I'm having a problem with the product list configuration of hybris. I'm more than sure that the answer of this issue is pretty simple, but I can't solve it. So here is the problem.

I have one homepage with one link, assigned to the navigation bar. Whenever the link is pressed I want to get redirected to a product list page where a list of all products of certain category will be displayed. However, I managed to do this, but anytime I change the name of a certain product something happens and the page stops displaying. It throws an error saying it is looking for the old name of the product I've edited.

For example, if the product name is Product1, the page is displayed, then I go and change the name to Product2 and when I press on the link, it throws an error Product with code 'Product1' not found! If I want this to be fixed, I have to create a new Product1 and I'm more than sure that this is not the right way it should work. Is there any synchronization that I need to do after making changes in the catalog or something of this kind? Any help will be appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I recommend you try two things that may resolve your issue.

1. When you make a change to a product, you will more than likely do it to the staged catalog. This is your intermediary to ensure information is correct before going live (especially useful if you have a workflow process in place). In order to synchronise this information, you will need to login to the product cockpit (your-server:9000/productcockpit). Find the staged version of the catalog on the left hand menu, right click on it, and select "Sync Selected Versions". This will transfer your information into the Online catalog.
2. When you arrive on the product listings page and the search results page, the information contained is more than likely indexed by SOLR. In order for any changes to be reflected, you will need to re-index. To do this:

   - Go to the HMC and login (your-server:9000/hmc/hybris)
   - In the navigation menu to the left, click on **System > Facet Search > Indexer Operation Wizard**
   - A pop-up window will appear. Select the Indexer operation as **update** and the Solr configuration to the index associated with your website.
   - Click start and the re-indexing will begin. It shouldn't take too long
   - If this fails, then you may need a full re-index instead

I hope this will help; I recommend you set up a Cronjob to re-index periodically in future, to keep your website up to date with your product management.

Comment: Thank you so much, a re-index was needed, I started it and everything seems to be fine, I'll have to assign a CronJob to manage it automatically :)

Answer (score 0):

PLP(Product Listing Page) fetches data from Solr. So whenever you are changing anything that is referred in the PLP, you need to update your indexes in Solr.

As you have changed the product name, update the Solr index from hmc.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I have one more question - do you have any idea what is the procedure of uploading an image and viewing it in the  products page, anytime I do so there is no image, just a thumbnail "image coming soon", but in the HMC the image itself is uploaded and everything seems just fine...